# Included .aspx files in Sonar Project

Tags: sonarqube

I have a C# sonar project that is used to analyse and review code. But I would like to included the aspx pages. I believe there is no plugin that is capable of analysis aspx but I would be happy  for the file just to appear in the project, so that I can take advantage of the review capability in Sonar.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible with the Sonar .NET & C# plugins ecosystem - nor with any existing plugin in Sonar for the moment.

Comment: Thanks, that is unfortunate. But I guess the main purpose of Sonar is code inspection, and not code review.

Comment: We're heading to code review step by step, and that's why I precised "for the moment" ;-) One day, you'll be able to review your ASPX files in Sonar... but I just can't give you an ETA for now.